# multi-part identifier with openrowset

Tags: multipart

Hi  consider the following code;

```
use jefftest;
insert into rep_track with (tablockx) (end_date, end_time)
(select end_date, end_time
from openrowset(bulk 'c:\scripts\sql-stuff\j.log', formatfile='c:\scripts\sql-stuff\endtime.fmt') as dummy
where [rep.track].[run] = 2175 and [rep_track].[rep] = 1)
```

the error I get is

```
 multi-part identifier "rep_track.run" could not be bound
 multi-part identifier "rep_track.rep" could not be bound
```

if I put a ")" after dummy and comment out the "where" cause it works (but I need the "where" cause), seems to be a problem with the "where" cause. any suggestion??

Comment: Hi Guys, it seems that I was using the wrong sql command, I should have used the UPDATE command. here's is what the working command string looks like;

Answer (score 0):

it seems that I was using the wrong sql command, I should have used the UPDATE command. here's is what the working command string looks like; 
use jefftest; 
update rep_track 
set end_date = i.end_date, end_time=i.end_time 
from (select end_date, end_time from openrowset(bulk 'c:\scripts\sql-stuff\j.log', formatfile='c:\scripts\sql-stuff\end_time.fmt') as dummy) i 
where rep_track.run=2175 and rep_track.rep=1